# Neo4j Is there a way to list running cypher queries in server?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using community edition 4.3.3. I started a long-time running query (graphsage training) from browser. Then my browser closed. When I am checking with "top" and "htop", process is still running. It is good, but there is way list running queries in the server ?

In addition is it possible to see query history ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to type `:queries` in your browser ?
Don't remeber if it's available in CE edition ...

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer posted by @logisima works for community edition. Also, I found that "CALL dbms.listQueries()" command which shows running queries. Is is also helpful.

Comment: in fact `:queries` is a shortcut of this command with a nice UI, where you can kill queries. BTW there is also a procedure to kill queries.